# Dynamic table html inside popover using Play Framework templating

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, playframework, popover, dynamic-html

I need to dynamically generate HTML inside a twitter bootstrap popover in table format using Play framework 2.0. But the following HTML code using Play framework's template is giving me syntax error. Could someone please guide me what is the correct syntax to achieve this ?

```
<a href="#" rel="popover"
data-original-title="Test dynamic table HTML inside popover" 
data-content="@(
"<table class='table table-bordered table-condensed'>" +
"<tbody>" +
    @for(item -> itemset) {
        "<tr><td>" + item.toString() + "</td></tr>" +
    }
"</tbody>" +
"</table>"
)"
</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

what is the syntax error? Does your itemset take scala parameters at the top of the template function?